# Ubuntu Touch build error

Tags: ubuntu-touch, porting-ubuntu-touch

I am trying to make a Ubuntu Touch build for my device (Redmi 2) using the cm sources that are already available but I've got no success at all.

As this guide asks: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/porting-new-device/ I was able to build for Nexus 4 without problems, but when I type lunch and then choose my device, I get the following:

> You're building on Linux
>
> Lunch menu... pick a combo:
>
> ```
>  1. aosp_arm-eng
>  2. aosp_x86-eng
>  3. aosp_mips-eng
>  4. vbox_x86-eng
>  5. aosp_hammerhead-userdebug
>  6. aosp_mako-userdebug
>  7. aosp_grouper-userdebug
>  8. aosp_tilapia-userdebug
>  9. aosp_flo-userdebug
>  10. aosp_deb-userdebug
>  11. aosp_manta-userdebug
>  12. cm_wt88047-userdebug
>  13. mini_x86-userdebug
>  14. mini_armv7a_neon-userdebug
> ```
>
> Which would you like? [aosp_arm-eng] 12
>   build/core/product_config.mk:222: *** Can not locate config makefile for product "cm_wt88047".  Pare.
>
> ** Don't have a product spec for: 'cm_wt88047'
>   ** Do you have the right repo manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Edit vendorsetup.sh in Your device tree according to Your device's config file, the config file could be like "full_2014813.mk".
 so 
eg.

add_lunch_combo full_2014813-userdebug

Comment: why '-1' ? The answer is perfect !